# I made a c program to calculate tax but doesn't seem to work fine

Tags: c

Calculate income tax paid by an employee to the government as per the slabs mentioned below:

```
 Income slab         Tax 
  2.5L-5.0L            5%
  5.0L-10.0L           20%
  Above 10.0L          30%
```

here 2.5L means 250,000

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float tax = 0, income;
    printf("Enter your annual income\n");
    scanf("%f", &income);

    if (income >= 250000 && income <= 500000)
    {
        tax = tax + 0.05 * (income - 250000);
    }
    if (income >= 500000 && income <= 100000)
    {
        tax = tax + 0.20 * (income - 50000);
    }
    if (income > 100000)
    {
        tax = tax + 0.30 * (income - 100000);
    }
    printf("Tax to be paid by you is Rs%f\n", tax);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: here 2.5L means 250,000.

Comment: What would it do if it "worked fine", and what is it doing instead?

Comment: It is calculating the wrong answers

Comment: According to the question, there should be no tax on amounts below 250,000 but it is still showing some amount as tax to pe paid .

Comment: I'm no expert in taxes, are you sure you did not enter something wrong here: `income >= 500000 && income <= 100000` ? Did you forgot a 0 as in 1_000_000 ?

Comment: C, or C++?  Choose one and edit the tags accordingly. `int main()` looks like C++, but the rest of the code looks like C.

Comment: Compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Be sure to read the documentation of your compiler and of your debugger

Comment: @fabian the `<=` and `>=` look like a bug (and likely are), but they don't affect the output. Look at how `tax` is updated when it's covered by both cases on a boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a few zeros. The line

```
income >= 500000 && income <= 100000
```

It is impossible for a value to be >= 500,000 and less than 100,000.

Did you mean 1,000,000? or 50,000?

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float tax = 0, income;
    printf("Enter your annual income\n");
    scanf("%f", &income);

    if (income >= 250000 && income <= 500000)
    {
        tax = tax + 0.05 * (income - 250000);
    }
    /// Changed "100000" to "1000000" in the following sections
    if (income >= 500000 && income <= 1000000)
    {
        tax = tax + 0.20 * (income - 50000);
    }
    if (income > 1000000)
    {
        tax = tax + 0.30 * (income - 1000000);
    }
    printf("Tax to be paid by you is Rs%f\n", tax);

    return 0;
}
```